# LogCat errors when Compiling App

Tags: android, database, compiler-errors, logcat

When i compile the app these errors show:

```
   sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table mensagens already exists
   Failure 1 (table mensagens already exists) on 0x240328 when preparing 'create table mensagens(mensagemsalva varchar(250),mensagemenviada varchar(250))'.
   sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table contatos already exists
   Failure 1 (table contatos already exists) on 0x240328 when preparing 'create table contatos(nome varchar(50),telefone varchar(20))'.
```

My Main.java has this code which is meant to create the database and its tables:

```
  onCreate(..){
   ...
  db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    ...
    VerificaDados();
  }

    private void VerificaDados() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        //cria uma TABLE de nome MENSAGENS
        db.execSQL("create table mensagens(mensagemsalva varchar(250),mensagemenviada varchar(250))");
        //ShowMessage("Banco","Criou a tabela de mensagens");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        }
    try{
        //cria uma TABLE de nome CONTATOS
        db.execSQL("create table contatos(nome varchar(50),telefone varchar(20))");
        //ShowMessage("Banco","Criou a tabela de contatos");
    }catch (Exception a){

    }

}
```

idk what it can be because i just run the app and BAM, errors in LogCat.

Comment: These are not compiler errors, but errors occuring as soon as your app launches. Have you ever read the error messages? You're trying to create tables that already exist.

Comment: (i thought it was compile errors, sorry x.x) Well i do know they exist but if you see they are "try" and "catch" and by the way i have been using this along and no problems like this have happened before

Comment: try-catch catches exceptions, the logged errors are no exceptions but merley some output of sqlite.

Comment: but exactly like the `openOrCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look athe the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) API Docs.

> this class takes care of opening the database if it exists, creating
>   it if it does not, and upgrading it as necessary.

You should try to distinguish between `onCreate()` and `onUpdate()`.

Comment: Yep i kinda know that but my app doesnt have nor need it because its a app only for people in my job (around 15 people) but that dons't come to this, the thing is i had the same code before and it worked just as fine but not now dont know why

Comment: OK, but does the app crash at all, or are you only worried because of the SQLite error messages in the log file?

Comment: im worried because when opened app error messages in the log and after in the app when i try to alter a contacts value in database.

Answer (score 0):

Just Comment (//) the `VerificaDados();` because the tables are already created.

```
onCreate(..){
    ...
 db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    ...
   //VerificaDados();
   }
```