# Database update crashing app

Tags: android, database

Code:

```
    final String nome = nm.getText().toString();
            final String telefone = tlf.getText().toString();
            if(nome.length() != 0 && telefone.length() != 0){
                if(mIndex.equals("")) {                 
                    ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
                    valor.put("nome", nome);
                    valor.put("telefone", telefone);
                    db.insert("contatos", null, valor);
                    ShowMessage("Sucesso","O Contato " + nome + " foi salvo com sucesso");
                }
                else {
                    String[] whereArgs = {"nome", "telefone"};

                    ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();                          
                    dataToInsert.put("nome", nome);
                    dataToInsert.put("telefone", telefone);

                    db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+"' and telefone='"+foneant+"' ", whereArgs);
                    ShowMessage("Sucesso","O Contato " + nome + " foi editado com sucesso");
                }
            }
```

So, mIndex is the index of the Contacts in the previous acitvity(which i selected and clicked the item/contact and then passed the index to the new activity) so, if the EditTexts are already BLANK it will ADD a new contact, if the EditTexts have a value and get changed it will Alter the Clicked Contacts value (name/telephone). But when i hit the button SAVE it crashes my app but the error is in the `db.update` line.

`db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+"' and telefone='"+foneant+"' ", whereArgs);` so therefore i guess the whereClause or the whereArgs is wrong, but as i dont have high intelligence in Android programming.

Comment: Here, a [LINK[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589582/logcat-errors-when-compiling-app) to my other question, it has the LogCat errors and the code of my main.Java which now im not openning the "VerificaDados();" in my onCreate so the databases shows no errors.

Comment: try answer suggested by Mukesh Soni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the whereArgs here since you are attaching the arguments in the where clause itself. Just supply null to in place of whereArgs -

```
 db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+"' and telefone='"+foneant+"'", null);
```

But it is always better to use the arguments. It prevents sql injection and also takes care of escaping special characters. In your case -

```
db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome=? and telefone=?", whereArgs);
```

Also, your whereArgs is wrong. It should be -

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {nomeant, foneant};
```

Comment: Alright, it worked the:
`db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome='"+nomeant+"' and telefone='"+foneant+"'", null);` thanks for helping.

By the way, the `db.update("contatos", dataToInsert, "nome=? and telefone=?", whereArgs);` showed no error but it wasn't saving the values right.

Comment: it will. your whereArgs is wrong. It should be like this - 
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {nomeant, foneant};

Comment: Yes, i was just waiting the timing.